# Accessing Multiple Sites in XAMPP over Internet (Not Localhost)

Tags: apache, http, web, xampp, web-hosting

I am using XAMPP web server.

I have created many virtual hosts.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "E:/Servers/Server1"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "E:/Servers/Server2"
    ServerName local2

    <Directory "E:/Servers/Server2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can acess both websites in my local network as localhost and local2 respectively.

With my external IP, I can only access my first website over Internet.

But my question is, **how can I access my all virtual hosts over Internet** (though both have same IP), from another computer over different network in WAN?

I didn't find any solution to this.

Is it possible to access over Internet?

If Yes, please explain the detailed procedure.

Comment: Do you have domain names for your virtual hosts or do you just access them with an IP address?

Comment: Use a (dynamic) domain name service that provides sub-domains. That way your web server virtualHost can work out which website you what to process.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the second one over the internet as well but for that you will need to add this into the other computer hosts file (located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc):

your internal IP address     local2

Example:
192.168.1.65         local2

This is the only way I know at this moment, if there is another solution that does no require to modify the hosts file of the other computer it will be interesting for me as well.